# How do you create a skybox in Fortnite's Creative Mode without the actual sky showing through?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I've spent over an hour trying to figure this out. I know that you need to place a barrier down and set it to the nebula or star field that you want to be displayed, make it its maximum size and have it set to hollow so players can still move around inside. I've done all that, but for some reason the color of the island's natural sky still shows through the walls of the barrier. It's fine for the blue nebula and star field, but it messes up the other colors, which are the ones I want to use. I've had to adjust the fog and lighting settings to make it work, but when I do that the lighting isn't bright enough.

I tried looking at the Space Showcase island template to figure out how they did it, but I honestly have no idea how they got the nebula to appear everywhere. It's seems like the entire sky has just been replaced. Even when I fly above the orange out of bounds wall the sky still looks like the nebula. I don't know how they managed it.

What am I missing here? How to I set up a solid skybox that won't show the actual sky at all?

Comment: I can't even remember how I used to do it now.

Are you sure there's no setting for transparency? Screenshots would help to see the kind of effect you're talking about.

Comment: No, there's not. The star fields and nebulae are supposed to be opaque, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having to botch a lot of workarounds to Creative Mode issues.

If you're sure there are no other settings relating to transparency, maybe try building walls of solid boxes, so you're outside the box rather than inside.

You could also try setting it as night time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not really sure what you mean by "try building walls of solid boxes, so you're outside the box rather than inside." but I have tried changing the time setting. I initially had it set to night time and switched it to midday instead. The blue of the night sky showed through far more than the day sky. The blue of the day sky still shows through, but not as much. It's still not great though.

Comment: @Demon Use boxes like walls, you get me? Make them long and tall, 4 sides and one big flat one on the top! Just something to try really, it's been a while since I [used to play Creative Mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FiNgERSYc0) but sometimes it would take me a whole day to figure a workaround for something. Then Epic would do an update and it WOULDN'T WORK ANYMORE!! That's why I ceased my creatioions.